# expected unqualified-id before string constant including ZenLib/Ztring.h

Tags: c++, c

In the included ZenLib header file I have this define configuration

```
//Char types
#if defined(__UNICODE__)
    #if defined (_MSC_VER) && !defined (_NATIVE_WCHAR_T_DEFINED)
        #pragma message Native wchar_t is not defined, not tested, you should put /Zc:wchar_t in compiler options
    #endif
    typedef wchar_t Char;
    #undef  __T
    #define __T(__x) L ## __x
#else // defined(__UNICODE__)
    typedef char Char;
    #undef  __T
    #define __T(__x) __x
#endif // defined(__UNICODE__)
#ifdef wchar_t
    typedef wchar_t wchar;
#endif // wchar_t

//***************************************************************************
// Platform differences
//***************************************************************************

//End of line
extern const Char* EOL;
extern const Char  PathSeparator;
```

Last two lines fail to compile with this message:

```
../ZZZ/ZenLib/Conf.h:243: error: expected unqualified-id before string constant
../ZZZ/ZenLib/Conf.h:243: error: expected initializer before string constant
make: *** [mediainfo.o] Error 1
```

Can anybody give an insight what does compiler expect here? Tagged as c++ too, because its compiled as a cpp file.

from the point of application it should be typedefed to a `char`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the header files that you include contains a definition for `EOL`, making the declaration

```
extern const Char* EOL;
```

look like

```
extern const Char* '\n'; // or '\r', or a numeric constant
```

Renaming your `EOL` to something different, say `Eol`, or `EOL_CHAR` should help.

Comment: @Ulterior as a rule of thumb all identifiers with only capital letters, digits and underscore that start with underscore or `E` are reserved by the C standard. And also custom is to reserve all-caps identifiers for the preprocessor.